# ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace when creating a conditional column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

given this dataframe named df:

```
Number  City    Country
one     Milan   Italy
two     Paris   France
three   London  UK
four    Berlin  Germany
five    Milan   Italy
six     Oxford  UK
```

I would like to create a new column called 'Classification' based on this condition:

**if df['Country'] = "Italy" and df['City'] = "Milan", result = "zero" else result = df['Number']**

The result I want to achieve is this:

```
Number  City    Country Classification
one     Milan   Italy   zero
two     Paris   France  two
three   London  UK      three
four    Berlin  Germany four
five    Milan   Italy   zero
six     Oxford  UK      six
```

I tried to use this code:

```
condition = [(df['Country'] == "Italy") & (df['City'] == 'Milan'),]
values = ['zero']
df['Classification'] = np.select(condition, values)
```

the result of which is this dataframe:

```
Number  City    Country Classification
one     Milan   Italy   zero
two     Paris   France  0
three   London  UK      0
four    Berlin  Germany 0
five    Milan   Italy   zero
six     Oxford  UK      0
```

now I try to replace the '0' in the 'Classification' column with the values of the column 'Number'

```
df['Classification'].replace(0, df['Number'])
```

but the result I get is an error:

*ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-value and non-None to_replace*

I would be very grateful for any suggestion on how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `np.where`

```py
df['Classification'] = np.where((df['Country'] == "Italy") & (df['City'] == 'Milan'), 'zero', df['Number'])
```

```
print(df)

  Number    City  Country Classification
0    one   Milan    Italy           zero
1    two   Paris   France            two
2  three  London       UK          three
3   four  Berlin  Germany           four
4   five   Milan    Italy           zero
5    six  Oxford       UK            six
```

If you want to use `np.select`, you need to specify `default` argument

```py
condition = [(df['Country'] == "Italy") & (df['City'] == 'Milan'),]
values = ['zero']
df['Classification'] = np.select(condition, values, default=df['Number'])
```